# What's the phrase for "learning throughout one's life"?

Tags: phrase-requests

How should one refer to somebody who wants to gain knowledge all the time and keeps learning in life even when very old?

What's the phrase for the same? My dictionary says "learn and live."

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes there is no direct translation for a specific phrase. I have heard people use phrases like, "He is a life-long learner."

Answer (score 4):

Lifelong learning, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifelong_learning

Answer (score 3):

**Lifelong learning** is the obvious answer, but in case you need something more sophisticated, you could go for **opsimathy**.

"An **opsimath** is someone who begins, or continues, to study or learn late in life." (Ref: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opsimath)).

Answer (score 2):

Pearson's tagline:
Always Learning